# Doctrine - Preserve linebreak on insert to MySQL database in Textarea?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Im using Doctrine for a CMS type of app.  Currently in  textareas, the data is being written to the MySQL database without any of the line breaks being preserved (no '\n' are appearing in the DB)

How do I make Doctrine preserve the line breaks?

Comment: yep, you're right!  The Linebreaks weren't being display in my MySQL DB, but when I did nl2br(), they came out on the front.  thans!

Comment: I've moved my comment to an answer. What were you using to view the raw MySQL DB data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't say I've ever seen this happen. Are you sure the line breaks aren't actually there?

Remember when outputting the content in HTML to run it through `nl2br()`